# Clear all inputs int html file by a method inside typescript file in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

In Angular project I have multiple inputs inside html file that are not wrapped with a form.

I need to clear all the inputs by a function inside TypeScript file.

I used ViewChild but seems that ViewChild must be unique.

I am using angular 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you have to use document.getElementbyID().value = "" to clear all the input fields it is always better to wrap them in a form if you want to clear the input controls.